# Strange video distortion capturing video from GV-USB2 on Linux using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-capture, v4l2

I'm trying to capture video from a GV-USB2 (a popular composite/S-Video capture card) on a Raspberry Pi 4B running Raspbian Buster. I built and installed [these V4L2 drivers for the GV-USB2](https://github.com/Isaac-Lozano/GV-USB2-Driver), and when I try to capture video over S-Video, I get some strange distortion which looks like displacement of the "viewport".

The capture card produces normal output on a Windows computer using the official drivers (Windows-only).

Output of `v4l2-ctl --all`:

```
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : gvusb2
        Card type        : gvusb2
        Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3
        Driver version   : 5.10.17
        Capabilities     : 0x85200001
                Video Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x05200001
                Video Capture
                Read/Write
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 1 (S-Video: ok)
Video Standard = 0x00001000
        NTSC-M
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 720/480
        Pixel Format      : 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
        Field             : Interlaced
        Bytes per Line    : 1440
        Size Image        : 691200
        Colorspace        : SMPTE 170M
        Transfer Function : Default (maps to Rec. 709)
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default (maps to ITU-R 601)
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
        Flags             :
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Frames per second: 29.970 (30000/1001)
        Read buffers     : 2

User Controls

                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128 flags=slider
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128 flags=slider
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128 flags=slider
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128 flags=slider
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=15 step=1 default=0 value=0 flags=slider
                 vertical_start 0x0098f900 (int)    : min=1 max=4 step=1 default=2 value=2 flags=slider
               horizontal_start 0x0098f901 (int)    : min=0 max=8 step=4 default=4 value=4 flags=slider
```

Result of `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -t 10 gvusb2-test.mp4`: https://youtu.be/Eqn_zlZJVx0

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of video distortion]

Using the `yadif` video filter helped to remove interlacing effects.
Result of `ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -vf yadif -t 10 gvusb2-test-yadif.mp4`: https://youtu.be/t13SVu5o-Sc

Screenshot:
[image]

If it means anything, the audio works fine using the accompanying sound drivers from the same repository.

If someone could help me or give me something to Google that'd be great. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried grabbing the raw output using v4l2-ctl and confirmed the issue existed there as well. So it turns out it's actually nothing to do with ffmpeg.